# How to use the embed code provided by Tableau in Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, embed, tableau-api

I'm trying to embed a tableau visualization onto a block created in Drupal 8. I've tried use one of the example tableau visualizations available [here](https://public.tableau.com/en-us/s/gallery/greenhaus-gas-emissions-eu?gallery=votd). Clicking on share on the on the tableau visual provides an embed code and I tried copying and pasting that embed code into a basic page with full html option in Drupal 8, but I don't see the visualization rendered. Instead the pasted content gets displayed as it is. How should i get this working?

Comment: Please provide more details and show the code that you are using.

Comment: In Drupal 8,  I clicked Content >>Add Content>>Basic Page. Filled up title field. copy pasted the embed-code from Tableau on to the Body section, set the text format to Full HTML.Clicked Save and Publish. in the Content page selected the new content and promoted it to front page. Now when i go back to the site, it just prints the content as text instead of rendering the tableau visualization.

Comment: I couldn't paste the embed code here. but you can see that when you click on the link i had stated on the question and on the visualization click on share. you will see the embed code

Answer (score 0):

I just figured one way of doing this. Copy the embed code onto a .html file and place it in the drupal web directory - in htdocs. On the content have a provide a hyperlink to the .html file. and there... it works!

Answer (score 0):

Just goto clicked Content >>Add Content>>Basic Page. and then in text editor click source button, then copy paste your tableau embedded code and click save & publish. then goto website and see the result.